# JSF multiple input text (One of them is required)

Tags: java, validation, jsf, input

I have JSF Page where lets say I have

First Name: *_*_

Last Name :*_*_

City: *_*_

State: *_*_

||Person Search||

Lets say I have a Search button.
So if a user enters one of the fields (FirstName or LastName or City or State) then he can press Search or else it should Error out.

I am not sure how to do this? In JSF how can you do a validation without going into the Bean Class for "One of the field is required". I do not want to use Validator because for every field it has to go to the Validator Class and probably I might have a performance hit. 
Please let me know if you have any solution to this. Thanks for the help, I appreciate.